# Mongoose errors on large updates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was trying to remove all documents from my collection in Mongoose when I discovered a recurring error for all queries that affect large numbers of documents. I have a schema set up and function setup as follows:

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' ),
    _ = require( 'lodash' ),
    request = require( 'request' ),
    helper = require( './helper' );

// Set up our spider schema with oldPath being our unique key to avoid duplicates
var gnatSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    oldPath: { type: String, unique: true },
    newPath: String,
    content: String,
    indexed: { 'type': Boolean, 'default': false },
    template: String
});

// Declare model and export
var Gnat = mongoose.model( 'Gnat', gnatSchema );

// Reset all gnats to not being indexed
exports.reset = function( cb ) {
    Gnat.update( { }, { indexed: true }, { multi: true }, cb );
};

// Remove all gnats
exports.clear = function( cb ) {
    Gnat.remove( {}, cb );
};
```

However both the reset and clear functions throw the following error after the first few documents are altered (the number the successfully change seems to be random):

```
{ [MongoError: Exec error: PlanExecutor killed]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'Exec error: PlanExecutor killed',
  index: 0,
  code: 96,
  errmsg: 'Exec error: PlanExecutor killed' }
```

The database I'm working with is on the large side, around 2700 documents, but the issue persists even when its down to under 1000 after multiple calls to clear.

I fear it might have to do with my Mongo setup itself? I'm currently just running Mongo locally via a daemon and it's been working well besides this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well I cleaned out my database and reimported from a backup and that seems to have fixed it for now. I'll post again if the situation changes. My guess is the database IDs and/or pointers got messed up during my debugging.